# $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous, $f(f(0))=0$ so there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(2a)=3a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous such that $f(f(0))=0$.
Prove that there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(2a)=3a$.

Well, I figured that in such exercises, I should define a new function and then use the Intermediate Value Theorem. In this case, defining $g(x)=f(x)- {3 \over 2}x$  does the trick, but this is after looking at the solution.

My question - Is there a way to see what function I should define? Like "reverse-engineering" the exercise?

Thanks

Comment: $a$ should be nonzero.

Comment: Then, $f(x)=x$ will be a counterexample if $a$ must be nonzero.

Comment: If a=0 we are done

Comment: It only says $f(f(0))=0$.

Comment: if $f(x)=x$ then a=0 will do.

Comment: @user3697301 You didn't read my comment clearly.

Comment: If intermediate value theorem was useful, I would expect it to be useful on $g(x) = f(2x) - f(3x)$. The reverse-engineering is simple: take the equation you wish to satisfy, pull everything to one side, and the resulting function is your $g(x)$. That's the way it works in all questions I've seen in recent memory.

Comment: @Batominovski I read it, before you edited .

Comment: @TheoBendit I tried $g(x)=f(2x)-f(3x)$ but it didn't help...

Comment: I believe you, but that's the most common process of reverse-engineering. Anything else, and I imagine it requires some uncommon properties, specific to the problem, and I'm not certain I can help you there.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for trying, i hope someone else could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof outline would be as follows:

- If $f(0) = 0$ then take $a = 0$.
- If $f(0) > 0$ then $f$ decreases from $f(0)$ at 0 to 0 at $f(0)$ in which case by the Intermediate Value Theorem it crosses the line $y = \frac{3}{2}x$ and we may take $a$ to be $\frac{1}{2}$ of the value of $x$ at the intersection.
- If $f(0) < 0$ then $f$ decreases from 0 at $f(0)$ to $f(0)$ at 0 and we argue similarly.

As for how to determine what function to define, suppose you want to show that two functions, $f$ and $g$, intersect on an interval $[u, v]$ and $f(u) < g(u)$ and $f(v) > g(v)$. Then apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to $f - g$, which is negative at $u$ and positive at $v$. It is easy to see that if $f(0) > 0$ then this setup applies to $f$ and $x \mapsto \frac{3}{2}x$ with $u = 0$ and $v = f(0)$.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it does mean $f(2a)=3a$. I'll edit, please do the same.

Comment: note that I have the proof, I just want to see how to come with this solution on my own. thanks

Comment: @user3697301 I added some info about that. Let me know if it's sufficient.